# React bug: setState - setInterval simultaneously

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I have a small react program. After click on start, there is a ball moving down the screen. When it reaches certain point, it should disappear and start from begin. However doesn't work like expected. The movement is created by setInterval function and increasing position in state. However it is strange. Ball is moving, but at the place where is console.log made, state.position is always 0. It should be current value of state. Why is it all the time 0?
Lastly, I shouldn't change state format. I know it's not usual state format, but I need this format for some other reasons.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function BallMoving () {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    intro: true,
    position: 0
  })

  const updateMoving = () => {
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, intro: false }))
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(state.position)
      if (state.position === 50) {
        setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, position: 0 }))
      }
      setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, position: prevState.position + 1 }))
    }, 30)
  }

  if (state.intro) {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => updateMoving()}>Start</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px', position: 'relative', border: '1px solid black' }}>
      <div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: state.position + 'px', left: '10%', width: '10px', height: '10px', backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try to add another `useEffect` hook like this: useEffect(() => { console.log(state) }, [state]); Remove the `console.log` inside `updateMove` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you call setState, React creates a brand new object which replaces the previous state. The setInterval callback meanwhile has no access to this new state as it is created with a reference to the current state and doesn't get any updates. What you can do is move your check into the callback of setState, which always has the latest state.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your logic a little bit to avoid `stale state`:

```
function BallMoving() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    intro: true,
    position: 0,
  });

  const [startMoving, setStartMoving] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(startMoving){
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, intro: false }));
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(state.position);
        if (state.position === 50) {
          setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, position: 0 }));
        }
        setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          position: prevState.position + 1,
        }));
      }, 30);

      // clear your interval to avoid memory leak
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [state])

  if (state.intro) {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setStartMoving(true)}>Start</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        position: "relative",
        border: "1px solid black",
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: state.position + "px",
          left: "10%",
          width: "10px",
          height: "10px",
          backgroundColor: "red",
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```